# Use TinyMCE from Grappelli

Tags: django

I want to change my TinyMCE theme

[image: tinyMCE circa 1995]

into a theme from Grappelli like found [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/wiki/tinymce). Any help? I really feel the documentation in the link isn't that complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out the solution.

First in my `settings.py`, I removed the tinymce then added

```
class Media:
   js = ['/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
   '/static/grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
   ]
```

on my `admin.py`